# Get the clicked radio button Id in the change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several groups of radio buttons with the same name.

I want to get the id of the clicked radio button in the change event. There are several answers related to this question but they all return the id of the **checked** one but what i want is **clicked** radio id.

**Updated**
Here is my code:

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=SltOptionPane]').change(function () {
  debugger;
  //here i want to get the clicked id of the radio
  var selectedValue = $("input[name=SltOptionPane]");
  alert(selectedValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" data-toggle="buttons" id="26Panel">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="btn btn-chackbox checkbox-lable-styles active" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-white"></span><input type="radio" name="SltOptionPane" value="27" id="27" autocomplete="off"><text>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;طبيعي</text>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="btn btn-chackbox checkbox-lable-styles" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-white"></span><input type="radio" name="SltOptionPane" value="29" id="29" autocomplete="off"><text>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ضعيف</text>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" data-toggle="buttons" id="27Panel">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="btn btn-chackbox checkbox-lable-styles active" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-white"></span><input type="radio" name="SltOptionPane" value="30" id="30" autocomplete="off"><text>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;طبيعي</text>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="btn btn-chackbox checkbox-lable-styles" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-white"></span><input type="radio" name="SltOptionPane" value="31" id="31" autocomplete="off"><text>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ضعيف</text>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help ,Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: You should use `this` object,  please check my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use *this* to refer the current element.

Try `$(this).attr('id');`

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=SltOptionPane]').change(function () {
  debugger;
  //here i want to get the clicked id of the radio
  var selectedValue = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(selectedValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" data-toggle="buttons" id="26Panel">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="btn btn-chackbox checkbox-lable-styles active" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-white"></span><input type="radio" name="SltOptionPane" value="27" id="27" autocomplete="off"><text>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;طبيعي</text>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="btn btn-chackbox checkbox-lable-styles" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-white"></span><input type="radio" name="SltOptionPane" value="29" id="29" autocomplete="off"><text>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ضعيف</text>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" data-toggle="buttons" id="27Panel">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="btn btn-chackbox checkbox-lable-styles active" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-white"></span><input type="radio" name="SltOptionPane" value="30" id="30" autocomplete="off"><text>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;طبيعي</text>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="btn btn-chackbox checkbox-lable-styles" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-white"></span><input type="radio" name="SltOptionPane" value="31" id="31" autocomplete="off"><text>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ضعيف</text>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jquery on click input (on input you can also put class):

```
$(document).on('click', 'input', function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Here is working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m7r5z9g1/

Comment: This will work but this will trigger all other click events that i do not want

Comment: That is why i added `on input you can also put class`

Comment: Like `$(document).on('click', 'yourClassName', function(){`

Answer (score 0):

At first give all radio buttons same class like "MyRadio" then create the following event.

```
$('.MyRadio').off('click').on('click', function(){
  alert(this.attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the prop method in order to retrieve the id of the selected item.

Here below is snippet of the Onchange function :

```
$('input[type=radio][name=SltOptionPane]').change(function () {
  debugger;
  var currentValue = $(this).prop("id");
  alert(currentValue);
});
```

Here is the link for the [demonstration](https://codepen.io/redhatvicky/pen/pBjvPz?editors=1111):

More Insights :

The .prop() method gets the property value for only the first element in the matched set. It returns undefined for the value of a property that has not been set, or if the matched set has no elements. To get the value for each element individually, use a looping construct such as jQuery's .each() or .map() method.

[Reference :](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop1)